# Installing Proprietary Driver and Updating sources.list

Tags: apt, drivers, package-management, proprietary-drivers

Trying to install the following firmware:

https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/firmware-realtek

Enabled `non-free` packages in `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
# 

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.8.0 _Wheezy_ - Official amd64 NETINST Binary-1 $

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.8.0 _Wheezy_ - Official amd64 NETINST Binary-1 2$

deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main non-free

# wheezy-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main non-free
```

Then performed the following:

- `sudo apt-get update`
- `apt-get install realtek-firmware`

Result:

> Unable to locate package realtek-firmware

How do I get this to work?

There's also an option to download the package. What command would I use to install from the downloaded package?

On a side-note, what's the wheezy qualifier in the `sources.list` file?

*sorta new here, appreciate the assistance*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. unless you're going to re-compile any of the packages, you don't need the `deb-src` lines - comment them out or delete them.  they just waste time and bandwidth downloading source package lists you're never going to use.
2. if you're going to have non-free, you may as well have contrib too.  i.e. have `main contrib non-free` on the `deb` lines instead of just `main non-free`
3. the package you want is called `firmware-realtek`, not `realtek-firmware`:

`apt-get install firmware-realtek`

Comment: is it recommended to install the non-free driver, then update `sources.list` after; so as to not install non-free packages in the future? will doing so affect my driver, with regard to updates?

Comment: if non-free isn't in your sources.list, you won't get updates to any non-free packages you have installed - including `firmware-realtek`.  if you don't want to risk accidentally installing other non-free packages, you'll have to keep an eye on the package and repeat this procedure every time there's an updated version.

Comment: thanks @cas, appreciate the help. was able to install it. but debian's telling me the wireless hardware switch is off, it's not ...